# Recreating a formula field from Salesforce in Tableau

Tags: salesforce, formula, tableau-api

I am trying to recreate a formula field that I created in SF over in Tableau that assigns a value to a specific picklist selection and then get a total.  There are 3 selections that need different values assigned.  I read somewhere in my research that the formula stops once it finds a match.  This is the first formula I tried but unless I make it a Dimension, it doesn't apply to all accounts with this criteria.

```
IF [Priority] = "Priority 1" THEN .5
    ELSEIF [Priority] = "Priority 2" THEN .25
    ELSEIF [Priority] = "Priority 3" THEN .1
    ELSE 0 END
```

I also tried some LOD formulas but that wasnt working either.

```
  {FIXED [Account ID]: MAX(IF[Priority] = "Priority 1" THEN .5
    ELSEIF [Priority] = "Priority 2" THEN .25
    ELSEIF [Priority] = "Priority 3" THEN .1
    ELSE 0
    END)}
```

I have watched a few videos and tried multiple things and nothing seems to work correctly.  This is only my third Tableau report so not up to speed yet on everything and can't seem to find what I am looking for in my google search.  Any guidance on how to apply values to a certain field selection for each account and get a total would be great.

Thanks so much for your help

```
  Full Name Account Name    Priority    Strat calc  Measure
  NAME      Account Name    Priority 1  0.5 
            Account Name    Priority 2  0.25    
            Account Name    Priority 3  0.1 
            Account Name    Priority 1  0.5 
            Account Name    Priority 2  0.25    0.25
            Account Name    Priority 3  0.1
```

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Comment: @bernardo added to the main question--it is just a mockup of what it does in the crosstab.   In measures, it only puts the value on 1 or two values for each account.